# configure max pool size hikaricp hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, configuration, hikaricp

I'm trying to use hibernate jpa and hikaricp for the CP.
But I have an issue that I dont understand, so either my config is bad ... or I do have something else.

this is the config In have in my persistence.xml file :

```
<properties>
    <!-- SQL -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatialDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        <!-- HikariCP -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle" value="5"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize" value="30"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.maxLifetime" value="150000"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user" value="user" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password" value="password" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.jdbcUrl"
            value="jdbc:mysql://server:3306" />
    </properties>
```

Still I'm having 100+ connections on the database. I thought that using maximumPoolSize it would have limit my number of connections. Is my configuration OK, based on my research it seems ok to me, but before trying to debug elsewhere I want to make sure it is.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be missing the `hibernate-hikari module jar` on your classpath. This module is `necessary` to integrate hibernate with `HikariCP`

Here is the [official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#database-connectionprovider-hikari)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand exactly from where this hibernate-hikari module is from ? and how to have that particular module on my classpath

Comment: ok it was a dependency I had to add in my pom file.
Right now I have another issue with that : 

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.extractIsolation(Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/Integer;

Comment: I had to update all my hibernate packages and modify a couple of things .. it works now. stangely I have an error in eclipse while running a test that i dont have in mvn (isValid() issue). but thanks !